# Maven archetype:create-from-project issues

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-archetype

I have a multi-modular Spring Boot application and I need to extract and Archetype from it.

When I lunch the command `mvn archetype:create-from-project` the archetype folder is created correctly but into the children modules I have a duplication of packages, I mean:

```
- archetype-resources
-- modulename
--- src/main/java
----_artifactId
---- my/company/_artifactId
```

I can't understand why the fixed "`my/company/_artifactId`" is generated alongside the correct one dynamic package "`_artifactId_`"

which config file I have to check in order to fix this issue: archetype_params.properties? archetype-metadata.xml?

Thanks.

SOLVED: The problem was due to the fact that I dind't do a `mvn clean install` but only a `mvn install`.